# Windows Version (Unable to confirm if installed Windows version is 10 or greater) in stable channel in Flutter

Tags: windows, flutter, version, flutter-doctor, windowsversion

I am having this problem when running `flutter doctor`

```
Windows Version (Unable to confirm if installed Windows version is 10 or greater)
```

I know it can easily be solved by changing the channel from stable to master, but doing so installs me a flutter beta version, while I would like to solve this problem by continuing to use a flutter stable version, is there a way to solve this problem?